# Getting Error in Overloading a program

Tags: java

Help me in Solving this Overloading Program

```
public class Overloading
{
void add()
{
    System.out.println("Default");
}
void add(int a)
{
    System.out.println("One Int Parameter is passed"+a);
}
void add(int a,int b)
{
    System.out.println("Two Int Parameter is passed"+a+" "+b);
}
    void add(int a,int b,int c)
{
    System.out.println("Three Int Parameter is passed"+a+" "+b+" "+c);
}
void add(char x)
{
    System.out.println("One Char Parameter is passed"+x);
}
void add(char x,char y)
{
    System.out.println("Two Char Parameter is passed"+x+" "+y);
}
    void add(char x,char y,char z)
{
    System.out.println("Three Int Parameter is passed"+x+" "+y+" "+z);
}
public static void main(String []args)
{
    Overloading d=new Overloading();
    d.add(z);
}
}
```

when i use d.add(1) or something other it works but using d.add("p") it does not work 
Help me Guys ....
and Thanx in Advance

Comment: try to add `d.add('p')` it will work :)

Comment: @AnoopKumarSharma: You should always be *much* clearer about what you mean by "not working". Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: thanx codemaker it works

Comment: wow an answer race condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using this call:

```
d.add("p");// you are calling a add() with parameter of type string
```

there is no such much method , so causing the error.
In order to make it work wither use:

```
d.add('p');// considered as char parameter
```

or add string parameter method as:

```
void add(String x)
{ 
   System.out.println("One String Parameter is passed"+x);
}
```

hope it will help!

Answer (score 1):

It works if you call it like this:

```
d.add('p');
```

Answer (score 0):

`"1"` is String and `'1'` is character. You need character here not String.

So do

```
d.add('p');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
d.add('p');
```

Your `void add(char x)` method takes parameter character not string. `'p'` is character whereas `"p"` is string.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps because "p" is a `string`, while you only have method accepting a `char`. You need another overload:

```
void add(string s)
```

Answer (score 0):

please change  `d.add("p");`
to

```
 d.add('p');
```

because char is 'p' not "p" (which is string type, and it would require `add(string s){}` function - that you miss)
you can also add:

```
void add(string s)
{
    System.out.println("One string Parameter is passed"+s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use,

```
d.add('p');
```

beacause your overload is for char not for string.